# Dynamical content doesn't not update when combining jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using PHP and MySQL to build a personal message system. The 'New-Message'-Counter needs to display the number of unread messages for each conversation. I am using a MySQL function to check the number of unread messages and a JQuery function to update the counter.

The problem is that the 'New-Message'-Counter is not working correctly. The expected output is to display the number of unread messages for each conversation. However, the variable `countMessages` doesn't contain the actual message count (as it is supposed to).

The SQL query to get the message count:

```
function check_unread_messages($chat_id, $from_id) {
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `messages` WHERE `group_id` = $chat_id AND `from_id` = $from_id AND `read_on` is NULL"), 0));
}
```

jQuery-Function where I call the SQL-query and try to update the div displaying the number of unread messages:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(setInterval(function() {
        friends_count = document.getElementsByClassName("user").length;
        for(var i=1; i < friends_count+1; i++) {
            el = document.getElementById(i);
            conv_id = el.getAttribute("data-user-id");
            user_id = el.getAttribute("data-conv-id");
            my_user_id = "<?php echo $session_user_id; ?>";


            cache = "check_unread_messages("+conv_id+", "+user_id+")";
            countMessages = "<?php "+cache+" ?>";
            
            if(countMessages > 99) {
                countMessages = "99+";
            }

            if(countMessages > 0 || countMessages == "99+") {
                document.getElementById("badge-"+i).innerHTML = countMessages;
            }
        }
    }, 500));
});
```

And this is the Container for the Counter:

```
<div class="user" id='<?php echo $i ?>' data-user-id='<?php echo $user_id?>' data-conv-id='<?php echo $conversation['id'] ?>'>
    // something, that doesn't matter
    <?php // normaly php gets opend in "something, that doesn't matter"
    echo "<div class='rightCountUnreadMessages'>";
        echo '<div class="badge" id="badge-'.$i.'"></div>';
    echo "</div>";
    ?>
</div>
```

In the jQuery Function `user_id` and `conv_id` are correct as far as I can tell. I guess, that there is something wrong with the 2 lines after that (`cache = ...`)

Comment: You cannot mix javascript and php like that, they execute in two different environments. If you need to get info from a php script (without leaving the current page) you have to do an ajax request.

Comment: But with other functions (without parameters) it works like this...

Comment: First the php executes. Then it's done. Javascript executes on the client. After the php has finished. I don't think this code is doing what you think it's doing...$i has no meaning if you think javascript can pass it to the php script.

Comment: What other functions? You cannot create a variable in javascript and have php read it, which is what you are trying to do with `cache`

Comment: But with some other functions (like i said without parameters) it works fine...

Comment: A better solution for you would be a tiny php file that can be requested asych, that expects a posted variable. Have the javascript invoke it for each loop instead.

Comment: Ajax is client side and php is server side, when you need updates from the server side (like mysql calls), you have to do a post or do an AJAX call to a php script which returns your data. Olease look into Ajax or Jquery Ajax.

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: With other functions that have no parameters, the php is executing first, then returning. You don't notice any problem because you aren't trying to pass client side variables to a server side script.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: The way I have done it works, without parameters but it seems so, that with parameters it doesn't work...

Comment: I cant work with Ajax pretty well, can anyone help me with my problem and solve it with Ajax please? :s...

Comment: As other commenters say, you seem to be mixing up server-side stuff (here php) with client-side stuff (here javascript). While it's true that you might render a php-variable like your `$session_user_id` onto your page (in a place that might happen to be some javascript), you still need some way of posting this to the server, e.g. an ajax-request (which I think is what you probably want). Quite frankly, I think you need to study some basics - e.g. you seem to be using your `countMessages` var as both a string and an int. Find some tutorials on php and javascript or maybe "web development" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to separate JS from PHP as possible, check the following example of how you can use AJAX requests to do that.

Create new PHP file called for example `check_unread_messages.php` contain :

```
$chat_id = $_POST['chat_id'];
$from_id = $_POST['from_id'];

$query = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `messages` WHERE `group_id` = chat_id AND 
          `from_id` = $from_id  AND `read_on` is NULL")

echo mysqli_result($query , 0);
```

And call it using ajax POST request `$.post()` like following :

```
$.post('check_unread_messages.php', {chat_id: conv_id, from_id: user_id}, function(result){
   //Here you get response of echo mysqli_result($query , 0); responce in 'result' variable
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And then result has the result in it?

Comment: Yep, try to check the value of result in console using  `console.log(result)`.

Comment: I have one more question, is there a difference between mysqli* and mysql*? Can I simply replace all mysql*-tags with mysqli*?

Comment: Yes you have to replace them by adding just `i`, because This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and  removed in PHP 7.0.0.